# PlayFramework shared Cache problem

Tags: playframework

Hi I'm creating subdirectories dynamically using routes, something like that

```
GET     /event/{nick}                           EventPageController.show
```

and I use it with something like that

```
example.com/event/congres2011
example/com/event/symposiumXI
```

then I get the first event in database and save in a key Cache

```
public static void show(String nick) {
        Event event = Event.find("byNick", nick).first();
        if (event == null) {
            redirect("/");
        }
        Cache.add("event", event);
        render(event);
    }
```

but when I request for the second (example/com/event/symposiumXI), the show method use the same key to save the new request event, for this reason the first event lost context. Please how can I controll it?, or maybe can I restringe to use onlyone event at same time...?

Comment: Instead of redirect("/") call Application.index(); (or whatever maps to "/"). It's better practice in Play.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the static key "event", it will be replaced. You might want to make it more context-aware by making the key something like `nick + "event"`.

Comment: thank a lot!, so, if I have this GET /event/{nick}/form , how can I get {nick} from form method?

Comment: You will get value in (String nick) argument of form method. See the doc http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/routes#Assignstaticargs

Comment: something like that GET /event/{nick}/form/{nick}  ?? , but the form's arguments should be send like Post, POST /event/{nick}/form/, Can I get {nick} from /event/{nick}/form/ ?